# Match Regular Expression with URL

Tags: regex, regular-language

Dears,

I've tried `"\b \b"` and  `(.*)["]` to get the regex which lets me select the url starting with "my.website" and ends with "myfile" for this URL in source code:

```
<a class="URL" href="http://my.website.com/a/b/cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/myfile" target="_blank">
```

any ideas please!

Comment: Please post the regex that you've tried, what it's matching, and explain where you think it might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
"(.*my.website.*myfile)"
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tI6vE1/1)

Then `$1` containing expected URL.

- `"` matches the characters " literally
- `(` capturing group
- `.*my.website` anything til `my.website`
- `.*myfile` anything til `myfile`

Answer (score 1):

this will be a generic solution

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=href=\"http://)[^\"]+" file

my.website.com/a/b/cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/myfile
```